# What is EOF in python? How to keep on taking input and printing it until the input is EOF?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, python-3.x, eof

I want to be able to keep on taking input in my program until input of EOF is given.
I know how to do it in c and I would like the corresponding code in python.

Input is:
1
2
3
EOF

Output is:
1
2
3

Here is the code in c:

```
while(scanf("%lld",&num)!=EOF)
  {
    printf("%lld\n",num);
  }
```